# Logs are missing after some days

Tags: java, maven, server

Log files are missing/deleted/archived from the folder after a few days later which was generated. How to debug as a system administrator whether it was an issue with the server level or code level (Maven Project).
There is no cronjob scheduled to do these tasks.

Please help me to debug the issue.

Comment: Consider a continuous integration server if you're wanting to track build histories like this

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which logging framework the project in question is using, you are not giving a lot of information. But most likely there is some form of log rotation configured, such as a [rolling file appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) in log4j or logback

Comment: Thanks, Epoch for your answer.Can I know what information required to elaborate on my issue?. is there any approach to find any hidden Task/Cron jobs that were scheduled at server level.